# How to retrieve value from <div contenteditable="true"> in Servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets, html, contenteditable

Here, I have a `<div contenteditable="true">`，which behaves the same as a `<textarea>` when clicked for edit. Users can type and edit text in it.

```
<label for="text_box" class="label">
    Body:   
</label>
<div class="text_box" name="text_box" id="text_box" contenteditable="true">
    <br />
</div>
```

I have also a servlet. How can I get the value of `<div>` in my servlet?

Comment: document.getElementById("text_box").innerHTML simplest way to get content of div with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create a form with a hidden `<textarea>` and a piece of JavaScript which copies the div's inner HTML content into the textarea's value on submit of the form.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
<form action="servletURL" method="post" onsubmit="this.content.value=document.getElementById('text_box').innerHTML;">
    <div id="text_box" contenteditable="true"><br /></div>
    <textarea name="content" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

*(note: using `onsubmit` and `style` attributes are a poor practice; use respectively jQuery's way of binding event handlers and a CSS file instead)*

This way it's in the servlet available the usual way as if `<textarea>` wasn't hidden:

```
String content = request.getParameter("content");
```